# NAFTA profession and position title

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, canadian-citizens

We have [NAFTA list of Professions](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/doing-business-in-america/professions-covered-by-nafta.html)  for Canadian Citizens to work in US.

If I need TN visa, should name from this list be present in the offer letter?

What is relation between position title and profession?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What annoys me to no end is that embassy pages look similar but similar content is not in the same place.

Having gotten my rant out of the way.  You can find the information regarding the format of the offer letter on several sites including one from the [US Embassy in Mexico](http://mexico.usembassy.gov/visas/non-immigrant-visas/visa-categories/nafta-visas-tn.html) and a [TNVISA Blog](http://tnvisa.blogspot.com/2011/07/sample-tn-letter.html#.VeYNsflVgXs).

It appears that you will need to have your position and qualifications listed on the letter.

Comment: probably I should use Canada Embassy page http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/doing-business-in-america/tn-visas-professionals-under-nafta.html instead Mexico.

Comment: @Alex I couldn't find the form letter on Canadian Embassy Page.

Comment: Maybe for Canadian is enough only offer? It's written there: "Provide a letter from the prospective U.S.-based employer offering him/her a job in the United States". I got offer with position title Technology Lead, but there is no such profession in NAFTA list. I requested TN Visa Support Letter from them: http://www.tnvisabulletin.com/contents-of-tn-employment-lett